# Can we Use Snowflake Tables functions in the procedure?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, java-stored-procedures

Experts,

I am trying to use tables function inside the snowflake procedure. However it throws me an error.

CREATE PROCEDURE
.....
....
extcnt ="select count(*) from table(information_schema.external_table_files(table_name=>''MYTABLE''))";
snowflake.execute({sqlText: extcnt});
.....

I  get below error message. Is there any restriction in using table function inside the procedure? Please Help.

"JavaScript execution error: Uncaught 100183-Stored procedure execution error: Requested information on the current user is not accessible in stored procedure"

Regards,
Gopi

Comment: Can you try `execute as caller`? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-rights.html

Answer (score 1):

Check the "Caller’s Rights and Owner’s Rights Stored Procedures" - this is probably the source of that error message:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-rights.html

When defining a stored procedure you can ask it to `EXECUTE AS CALLER`, which changes the access it has to different resources.

> Create a stored procedure as an owner’s rights stored procedure if all of the following are true: You want to delegate a task(s) to another user(s) who will run with the owner’s privileges, not the caller’s own privileges [...]

> Create a stored procedure as a caller’s rights stored procedure if the following are true: The stored procedure operates only on objects that the caller owns or has the required privileges on [...]

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sv_proc1()
    RETURNS VARCHAR
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    EXECUTE AS CALLER
    AS
    $$
...
```

Comment: Thanks it worked when is changed to caller. However in this procedure, I need to refresh  the external created by another User.  For refreshing the External table I need to be owner /Higher privilege. Hence we used EXECUTE AS OWNER . Is that a limitation as we cannot use Tables function when the procedure with OWNER instead of CALLER?

Comment: Did you try? What happened?